# order of magnitude of parameters in simulation change running time

Tags: floating-point, numeric, scientific-computing

I'm running a simulation, I realized for some parameters' values the simulation time can be varies, when the parameters are in the order of ~(10e9) the simulation run 20 times faster when I enter a parameters with order of ~(10e6). the code is quiet extensive I can't select a part of it to show you.
but I'm curious that is here anyone who have seen such thing and could explain it to me?

Comment: This could be anything. The code could take very different paths with different data. The code might encounter subnormal floating-point numbers with some data that it does not with others (and some processors process subnormal numbers much more slowly than normal numbers). No diagnosis can be made without considerably more information.

Comment: You might want to run the code under an appropriate tool like Linux's `perf` to diagnose where the extra time is spent.